# Trouble adding child record with Entity Framework

Tags: database, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am not understanding how to add a record with Entity Framework that is (or should be) a member of a collection (the parent). When I add the child class to the database, its foreign key does not get updated with the parent Id. What am I missing in my models or what do I need to do with my context to update the key after adding the child record?

I have models similar to the following:

```
[Table("Parents")]
public class ParentClass{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<ChildClass> ChildClasses {get; set;}
}

[Table("Children")]
public class ChildClass{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Data {get; set;}
}
```

In my code to add the child class I do something such as:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
  //a list of children gets created earlier...
  foreach(var child in children)
  {
   if(child.id == 0) //a new child record
    {
      context.Children.Add(child);
    }
    else
    {
      context.Children.Update(child);
    }
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

While the records for children are added, they have a foreign key to the ParentClass, but I do not see how to get Entity Framework to update that field in the database after having added the child record.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ChildClass` should at least have a `ParentId` property (mapped to the database FK field) and maybe also a `ParentClass` property.

Comment: I was looking here for reference: [link]https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#single-navigation-property

So, I should change my ChildClass and to include the parent like such: 

> public ParentClass Parent {get; set;}

and perhaps change my context class to may do this in OnModelCreating? 

> modelBuilder.Entity<ChildClass>().HasOne(p => p.ParentClass).WithMany(b => b.ChildClass);

Comment: @GertArnold has give you the answer, if you want to see the navigation property and the keys in your entity you should write in ChildClass ParentClassId and ParentClass.